# Firebase in Unity - Disable persistence

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile game for Android using Firebase. This game has a system that allows the player to play offline and update/retrieve data from the database depending on the saved date-time.

This date-time (written in a local file) should be the same as the one saved in the database, and to do so I wrote this:

```
reference.Child("users/"+this.id+"/updateDate").SetValueAsync(updateDate).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.IsCompleted) {
        Debug.Log("Setting new update date into file: "+updateDate);
        this.lastUpdateDate = updateDate;
        WriteFile();
    }
});
```

The problem is that, even if there is no internet connection, the value gets modified but the condition below is never satisfied so what happens is this:
If you read the value, even without internet connection, you read the "new" date-time, while the file still contains the "old" one (the one actually in the database).

I know the best solution is to delete everything and let offline persistence do its work, but I did a couple tests and it doesn't even work on Android's build. So my question is the following:

**Is there a way to disable offline persistence in Unity?**

Because I've tried *"FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.setPersistenceEnabled(false)"* but it seems like that function is not even present in the Unity's API (it gives me compile errors).

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I discovered there is a way to check if there's connection or not. I just hope it works on Unity.
Do there's a developer of Firebase that still knows the answer for the main question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable persistence, do:

```
Firebase.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(false);
```

---

If you're coming from Google with the "Failed to initialize persistence storage" crash when testing Unity with 2 editors, do

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
  Firebase.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(false);
#endif
```

Comment: I tried this but it still fetches old data from the database for some reason, is there another way to clear it?