# Unity Firebase Realtime keeps showing old data even if deleted

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app that uses Firebase Realtime Database.

I am retrieving data by using queries

```
query = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference(path).OrderByChild(childToSort).StartAt(startAt).EndAt(endAt);
```

When reading "/Users" node I am receiving 2 childs. So my log looks like this:

```
a) FIREBASE - Users - CHILD ADDED: -N1GP5RVhlM1joeWcQ9q

b) FIREBASE - Users - CHILD ADDED: -bt8rBUH2W1bKH2gzXsh
```

(Update) Then it gets removed almost instantly:

```
FIREBASE - Users- CHILD REMOVED: -N1GP5RVhlM1joeWcQ9q
```

**The Problem**
The problem only manifests sometimes.

"a)" Doesn't exist anymore because I deleted it on Firebase Console, but it is still showing at the beginning of each execution.

My own web admin panel (using REST API) doesn't show it anymore, which is right.

But "a)" still shows for a moment at the beginning of the execution. After this, it gets removed by itself as the log shows.

This is a problem because makes the beginning of the execution of my app a bit tricky. I can't have 2 users signed-in at the same time.

I remember I set `this.query.KeepSynced(true);`  for some test before this issue, but I have tried to change it to false or comment it. This doesn't make any difference.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Update:
After some testing, I found out new details about the issue. Because of this, I restructured this question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but if anyone needs it:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(false);
```

Its works for me

Answer (score -1):

## My experience

I had the same issue very often in Unity 2020.3.16f1 while getting data from my Firebase Realtime Database. Around half of my database getValueAsync() requests would grab outdated data that is around a week old. 

This also usually happens the first time I test my app. If I run it, quit it and run again within a minute, I sometimes retrieve the correct data. But if I wait a minute or two, I seem to always get outdated data.

I have seen no breaks in my internet connection but I do occasionally retrieve lower connection speed than normal. This leads me to believe that Firebase requires a certain connection speed minimum to retrieve data from a database before sending persisted data. I can see how this may be useful in some specific cases but with no control over what data is persisted and when, it is better to keep it off and use PlayerPrefs to manage data for offline play.

## My research

Following up on the vague advice of previous answers on this post, I looked into Firebase DataPersistence. Unfortunately, the only documentation about this in Firebase is for Android with java or cotlin. After some time searching online I found a similar issue that had a partly correct answer. However, it didn't state where to place the code or how to format it properly.

Also, I want to make it clear that I never enabled Persistence which means Firebase enables it by default and does not provide enough documentation for developers to disable it.

[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782602/firebase-in-unity-disable-persistence)

## My solution

```
FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("https://rtdb-Link.firebaseio.com/").SetPersistenceEnabled(false);
```

The above line of code set at the **very top of the Start()** function of my database script is the only way that I could get it to work. I have never been able to get `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance` to work so I use GetInstance() instead.